# Change in direction sensor

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, proximity-sensor, direct

Please is there a circuit that if a car travelling in a straight road turns in the opposite direction, a sensor would be able to know and give a signal. The sensor would still be attached to the car

Comment: Your question lacks detail.  Do you _just_ want to know if the car has reversed direction?  In what interval of time does the car reverse direction?  Is it acceptable to detect that the car has stopped and started again?  Can you hook up to the car's internal sensor suite (assuming a modern Western car)?

Comment: You could use a cheap accelerometer sensor, such as used in mobile phones. This will give you a relative movement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem by designing a simple circuit with IMU.
With a known starting location and precise acceleration measurements, the IMU provides information on current vehicle location and orientation.

Comment: You may want to subject that assertion to some mathematical analysis.  A typical cell phone IMU could maintain position, velocity, and orientation on a car for perhaps a few seconds _if_ the starting state were near-perfect and _if_ the IMU's offsets were known to a near-perfect degree.  For a drive longer than that -- no, you'd need sensor fusion between an IMU and some sort of position-oriented ground truth, such as GPS or video running into a good SLAM algorithm.